# Python make dictionary from list of different dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have the following list of dictionaries:

```
dict_list = [{'type': 'hr', 'data': '{"Name": "Name1","City": "city1", "EMail": "email1@gmail.com"}', 
             {'type': 'hr', 'data': '{"Name": "Name2","City": "city1", "EMail": "email2@gmail.com"}',
             {'type': 'it', 'data': '{"Name": "Name3","City": "city3", "EMail": "email3@gmail.com"}', 
             {'type': 'it', 'data': '{"Name": "Name4","City": "city2", "EMail": "email4@gmail.com"}', 
             {'type': 'op', 'data': '{"Name": "Name5","City": "city1", "EMail": "email5@gmail.com"}']
```

I would like to create new list of dictionaries from the existing list of dictionaries where If I have the same "type" in dict_list then append all data to make a single list of data dictionary as below expected list of dictionary:

```
expacted_dict_list = [{'type':'hr', 'data':'[{"Name":"Name1","City":"city1","EMail":"email1@gmail.com"}, {"Name":"Name2","City":"city1","EMail":"email2@gmail.com"}]'},                        
                      {'type':'it', 'data':'[{"Name":"Name3","City":"city3","EMail":"email3@gmail.com"},{"Name":"Name4","City":"city2","EMail":"email4@gmail.com"}]'},                        
                      {'type':'op', 'data':'[{"Name":"Name5","City":"city1","EMail":"email5@gmail.com"}]'}]
```

Please help to achieve any this expected output.so that later based on key type will post the data to a rest api endpoints for that type.

Comment: What have you tried?  This is not hard.  I would make one pass where I created a dict with `type` as the key and a list as the value.  After that, it's easy to convert to your output type.

Comment: Are the values under `data` key strings or dictionaries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does what you ask in a few lines.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from pprint import pprint

dict_list = [{'type': 'hr', 'data': {"Name": "Name1","City": "city1", "EMail": "email1@gmail.com"}}, 
             {'type': 'hr', 'data': {"Name": "Name2","City": "city1", "EMail": "email2@gmail.com"}},
             {'type': 'it', 'data': {"Name": "Name3","City": "city3", "EMail": "email3@gmail.com"}}, 
             {'type': 'it', 'data': {"Name": "Name4","City": "city2", "EMail": "email4@gmail.com"}}, 
             {'type': 'op', 'data': {"Name": "Name5","City": "city1", "EMail": "email5@gmail.com"}}]

tempdict = defaultdict(list)
for d in dict_list:
    tempdict[d['type']].append( d['data'] )

out_list = [{'type': k, 'data': v} for k,v in tempdict.items()]
pprint(out_list)
```

Output:

```
[{'data': [{'City': 'city1', 'EMail': 'email1@gmail.com', 'Name': 'Name1'},
           {'City': 'city1', 'EMail': 'email2@gmail.com', 'Name': 'Name2'}],
  'type': 'hr'},
 {'data': [{'City': 'city3', 'EMail': 'email3@gmail.com', 'Name': 'Name3'},
           {'City': 'city2', 'EMail': 'email4@gmail.com', 'Name': 'Name4'}],
  'type': 'it'},
 {'data': [{'City': 'city1', 'EMail': 'email5@gmail.com', 'Name': 'Name5'}],
  'type': 'op'}]
```

This ASSUMES that the quotes around your 'data' parameter were a mistake.  (You also omitted a closing `]` on each line -- you should always run the code before you paste it into a question).  IF the `'data'` member is actually supposed to be a JSON string, then you'd need an extra `json.loads` step in the first loop, and an extra `json.dumps` in the second loop.

### Followup

If my assumptions were wrong, then you need:

```
tempdict = defaultdict(list)
for d in dict_list:
    tempdict[d['type']].append( json.loads(d['data']) )

out_list = [{'type': k, 'data': json.dumps(v)} for k,v in tempdict.items()]
```

But certainly do double check this.  It's unusual (but not unheard of) to have JSON nested inside JSON.

Comment: my mistake to make it proper data.Yes data is JSON value from MYSQL JSON column.actually at the end I have to post the data as json to REST API endpoint.so trying to append all data key's value as a list of dictionaries and later convert that list of dictionaries to json data.

Comment: I need to post the data SFMC as per given documentation from Salesforce - [Link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/postDataExtensionRowsetByKey.html) . I do check again on this and will update here.

Comment: That example doesn't show JSON nested in JSON, but this is something you'll need to work out for yourself in your program's structure.  You could encode it later, when you send the request.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some errors in your formatting (missing `'` and `}` in the 1st, extra `'` in the second.
Once fixed, this should work:

```py
new_dict = dict()

for d in dict_list:
    new_dict[d['type']] = new_dict.get(d['type'], []) + [d['data']]

expacted_dict_list = [{'type': k, 'data': v} for k, v in new_dict.items()]
```

I'm using this as input:

```
dict_list = [{'type': 'hr', 'data': '{"Name": "Name1","City": "city1", "EMail": "email1@gmail.com"}'}, 
             {'type': 'hr', 'data': '{"Name": "Name2","City": "city1", "EMail": "email2@gmail.com"}'},
             {'type': 'it', 'data': '{"Name": "Name3","City": "city3", "EMail": "email3@gmail.com"}'}, 
             {'type': 'it', 'data': '{"Name": "Name4","City": "city2", "EMail": "email4@gmail.com"}'}, 
             {'type': 'op', 'data': '{"Name": "Name5","City": "city1", "EMail": "email5@gmail.com"}'}]
```

Output:

```
[{'type': 'hr',
  'data': ['{"Name": "Name1","City": "city1", "EMail": "email1@gmail.com"}',
   '{"Name": "Name2","City": "city1", "EMail": "email2@gmail.com"}']},
 {'type': 'it',
  'data': ['{"Name": "Name3","City": "city3", "EMail": "email3@gmail.com"}',
   '{"Name": "Name4","City": "city2", "EMail": "email4@gmail.com"}']},
 {'type': 'op',
  'data': ['{"Name": "Name5","City": "city1", "EMail": "email5@gmail.com"}']}]
```